# Get user login name in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

How to check login user name from the system in c# 
I tried it using this method

```
static string whoisLoggedIn(string HostOrIP)
{
     GUFlag = true;
     HostOrIP = Environment.MachineName;
     System.Management.ConnectionOptions myConnectionOptions = new System.Management.ConnectionOptions();
     myConnectionOptions.Impersonation = System.Management.ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;

     System.Management.ManagementScope objwmiservice;
     System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher myObjectSearcher2;
     System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection myCollection2;

     try
     {
         objwmiservice = new System.Management.ManagementScope(("\\\\" + (HostOrIP +
"\\root\\cimv2")), myConnectionOptions);
         objwmiservice.Connect();
         myObjectSearcher2 = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(objwmiservice.Path.ToString(),
"Select UserName from Win32_ComputerSystem");
         myObjectSearcher2.Options.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 7000);
         myCollection2 = myObjectSearcher2.Get();
         GUFlag = false;

         foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject myObject in myCollection2)
         {
             if (!(myObject.GetPropertyValue("Username") == null))
             {
                 string Userx = myObject.GetPropertyValue("Username").ToString();
                 int posx = Userx.LastIndexOf("\\");
                 if ((posx > 0))
                 {
                     Userx = Userx.Substring((posx + 1));
                     return Userx.ToUpper();
                 }
             }
         }
         return "<Nobody>";
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
         return "<Nobody>";
     }
     finally {

         GUFlag = false;
     }

 }
```

But the problem is some time deadlock occur on `myObjectSearcher2.Get();`
Is there any way available to get login username

Comment: Are you looking for who is logged in to the computer or who is logged in to your Asp.Net site? Also are you using Asp.Net membership?

Comment: I am trying to get user name in window service whib|chb

Answer (score 5):

did you try that?

```
Environment.UserName
```

it will give you the user name of the user currently login on windows

**EDIT**

I found this bit of code here http://www.debugging.com/bug/20243, it may solve your issue.

solution by using WMI ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx ):

```
    private string GetUserName()
    {
        string result = "";
        using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT UserName, Name FROM Win32_ComputerSystem"))
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
            {
                if (mo["UserName"] != null)
                    result = mo["UserName"].ToString();
                if (mo["Name"] != null)
                    result += " (" + mo["Name"].ToString() + ")";
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: When this is used in window service it returns System rather then real name, With out window service it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm not understanding you correctly, I believe it's just:

```
using System.Security.Principal;

this.nametext = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

Comment: Although every thing is clear then why you are getting confused?

Comment: When this is used in window service it returns System rather then real name, With out window service it works fine